# Linq - Find Missing values in a List<> - Terribly inefficient

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have a class defined as follows in my C# program:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string ID;
    public int Val;
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime EndDate;
}
```

And I have a huge `List<MyClass>` in my program and I need to check if there are any values in this list where:

1. A certain set of criteria are met (in this simplified example, suppose `Val != 0`, but the criteria is substantially more complex than that)
2. There is a corresponding value in the list (`ID`s match) with `StartDate` equal to this current value's `EndDate`

My current code is as follows:

```
var myTest = new List<MyClass>();

... populate myTest ...

var expectDt1 = myTest
                  .Where(v => v.Val != 0)
                  .Select(v => new {ID = v.ID, EndDate = v.EndDate});

var dontExist = expectDt1
                  .Where(tst => 
                         !myTest.Any(v => 
                             v.ID.Equals(tst.ID) 
                             && v.StartDate == tst.EndDate
                             )
                          );
```

This code works, but it's running terribly slowly (My list has many many thousands of entries). Is there a nicer way of doing this (grouping or something else) that would make this more efficient?

(PS - I do know I could make this into a more simplified Linq statement without needing the intermediate `expectedDt1` variable, but that didn't help the efficiency, so I simply wrote it like this to make my question more understandable)

Comment: Probably you chosed a bad datastructure for this. Can you give details about how many records are there, hom many !=0, how many repeating ids etc?

Comment: I'd try stuffing the list into `Dictionary<DateTime,Dictionary<int,MyClass>>`, where the key for the outer one is StartDate. Then you just grab all the ones with the right startdate and TryGetValue() each one for the ID. This all costs time to set up of course, but there's no redundancy. (Actually never mind -- this is a kludged up imitation of what Servy suggests in his answer below; I never heard of ToLookup before).

Comment: @EdPlunkett Rather than one dictionary nested in another, using one dictionary with a key that has multiple parameters is quite a bit more efficient (in both time and space).  And using `ILookup` (which is a very comparable structure to a `Dictionary` makes the code much cleaner in that it supports duplicates values for a key (which is fine with us) and allows us to pass in a non-existent key much more cleanly.

Comment: @Servy "TIL", as they say. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to create a hash-based lookup structure to look for items with the given values, rather than doing a linear search through a large list for every single item.

```
var lookup = myTest.Where(ItemIsValid)
    .ToLookup(item => new
    {
       item.ID,
       Date = item.EndDate,
    });
```

Then you get to go through your other collection to see if you can find a match in the lookup:

```
var query = expectDt1.Where(item => !lookup[new {item.ID, Date = item.StartDate}].Any());
```